# WCF REST service client calls mapped to wrong Uris

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST service, very simple, like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
           Method = "GET",
           UriTemplate = "getNumber")]
         int GetSomeNumber();
    }

public class TestService : TestServiceApp.ITestService
    {
        public int GetSomeNumber()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

It is configured like this:

```
<services>
      <service name="TestServiceApp.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehaviour" contract="TestServiceApp.ITestService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

It works fine called from the browser using the specified Uri template:

```
http://localhost:52602/TestService.svc/getnumber.
```

I configured my client like this:

```
 <client>
      <endpoint name="TstSvc" address="http://localhost:52602/TestService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TstSvc.ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehaviour"/>
    </client>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="restBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

When I'm calling the service with following code:

```
    using (WebChannelFactory<ITestService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<ITestService>("TstSvc"))
    {
        var svc = factory.CreateChannel(); 
        svc.GetSomeNumber();
    }
```

I get error:

> "There was no endpoint listening at
>   `http://localhost:52602/TestService.svc/GetSomeNumber` that could accept
>   the message."

I suspect that for some reason my calls using GetSomeNumber method aren't correctly mapped to the uri /getnumber. Why? How can I fix this, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I could think of is that your `ITestService` contract is not up to date in the `WebChannelFactory` client code.

I did notice in my testing that where you use `WebInvoke` matters. `WebInvoke` should always be placed on your `ServiceContract` (*interface*) so that `WebChannelFactory` has the proper URIs when communicating via REST. If you place `WebInvoke` on the concrete class (*implementation*) then `WebChannelFactory` defaults to the `OperationContract` name as you observed above.

Comment: but this is not what I'm trying to achievie. What you've suggested changes the name of the method itself - when it's identical to the uri of courese it will work. But it will not always be like this and I'd like to know what to do when it isn't.

Comment: are you absoluetely sure about that? I've seen an article today about cpnsuming twitter's rest service and they use both webchannel factory and have not matching contract name and uri (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/07/26/creating-a-rest-twitter-client-with-wcf.aspx). can you provide any reference for what you have stated?

Comment: No - you are correct, my testing was flawed, see edits above. Where you place the `WebInvoke` is important for `WebChannelFactory` to locate the `UriTemplate` properly.